# Why does Scala take less time to read a file if it's done multiple times?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to compare the time it takes to read a file for pyspark and scala spark. In Scala, I'm doing the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Playground extends App {
  def getDfFromFile(path: String, spark: SparkSession) = {
    spark
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("inferSchema", true)
      .option("header", true)
      .load(path)
  }

  val master = "local"
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master(master)
    .getOrCreate()
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

  val N = 1
  val avgTime = (0 until N)
    .map(_ => {
      val start = System.nanoTime()
      getDfFromFile("resources/bigdatafile.csv", spark)
      val end = System.nanoTime()

      end - start
    }).sum / Math.pow(10, 9)
  println(avgTime)
}
```

With `N = 1` this takes about 2.7 seconds. If I increase it to 10, it takes  about 3.7 seconds. With `N = 100`, it takes 9.7 seconds.

Clearly, the time increase is not linear in N. Why not? And what can I do to make it linear so that I can effectively compare how many times it takes to read a file *the first time* in Spark and PySpark?

EDIT:

If I change the code to create the sparkSession inside the map function instead:

```
  val N = 100
  val avgTime = (0 until N)
    .map(_ => {
      val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .master(master)
        .getOrCreate()
      spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

      val start = System.nanoTime()
      getDfFromFile("resources/bigdatafile.csv", spark)
      val end = System.nanoTime()

      spark.close()

      end - start
    }).sum / Math.pow(10, 9)
```

it has almost no effect on the result.

Comment: This is not Scala specific behavior. This happens because of caching on OS level.

Comment: @talex there is that. But before that, there is the performance of the classloader (first time access to spark classes), then of the initializing the system (HDFS, Hive metastores) then that of the just in time compiler (by creating a hot loop), and in the end, access to the top few kilobytes of the file (because no terminal operation occurs, spark only checks the top of the file, not its entirety). Any sensible, benchmarking, I guess, should aim at creating a real complete workflow. Merely instanciating a dataframe clearly is not representative of what will be costly in a real computation.

Answer (score 1):

Spark executing strategy is lazy, in your case it means spark will load data from the file just when you apply an action operation (collect, sink, ...) on it, but your code just compute the start and end time and aggregate it so there is no need to load data from the file!

For time evaluation, you should apply some logic on the file data (including action operation), for example, you can apply the Word Count algorithm or even you can just print any row.